# JSF 2 Execute action on button click

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have this JSF code

```html
<f:view>
    <h:form>                    
        <h:commandButton value="Generate License File" type="button" action="#{agreement.generateLicenseFile}"/>                    
    </h:form>
</f:view>
```

And this is the bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="agreement")
@RequestScoped
public class AgreementBean {

    private boolean generate=false; 

    public void generateLicenseFile(){
        generate=true;
    }
}
```

When I execute the app, and click on the button, absolutely nothing happens. There are no errors in the execution. It simply doesn't do a thing.

Any ideas?

--EDIT--

What I mean is that the boolean's value isn't modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I execute the app, and click on the button, absolutely nothing happens

Lot of things happen behind the scenes!

- It will trigget a `POST` request to the server that will be handled by the Faces Servlet.
- This starts the [JSF lifecycle](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf2/) and you can debug it following [this tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html). For the JSF lifecycle I will only explain the last two phases (the other links explains very well the other 4 phases, specially BalusC's).
- In the Invoke Application phase (5th phase) the server will execute the `generateLicenseFile` method bound to the `<h:commandButton>` in your `<h:form>`.
- Since you return nothing from this phase, then in Render Response phase (6th phase) will only retrieve the current view with the ViewState updated. Also, since you don't do a big update to any component in the view, you will see *nothing*.

Also, since the bean is configured to be `@RequestScoped` it will be created on every form submission and the `generate` field will be always `false`when being created on the request (since you're not changing its value in view it will remain with `false` value). The bean creation can vary depending on the declared scope. More info: [Communication in JSF 2: Managed bean scopes](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes).

If you want to *see* something in the view, I recommend you changing the code a little bit:

JSF code

```html
<h:form>
    #{agreement.generate}
    <br />
    <h:commandButton value="Generate License File" type="button"
        action="#{agreement.generateLicenseFile}" />
</h:form>
```

Managed bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="agreement")
@ViewScoped //removed RequestScoped, this WILL make the difference
public class AgreementBean {
    private boolean generate = false; 
    public void generateLicenseFile(){
        generate = !generate;
    }
    //getter and setter for generate field
}
```

Comment: What I mean is that the boolean's value doesn't change :P It seems as if the bean's method is not executed.

Comment: @Nacho321 it will change, but since the bean is `@RequestScoped` it will be created on every request. This can be *solved* by changing the scope of your bean to `@ViewScoped`. Check the update on my answer.